# How to get a string from requested array PHP

Tags: php, string, url, get, request

I have a file swifts.php with code (I have written this after a lot of research)

```
    <?php

$swift= array(
'PBANUA2XXXX' => 'PRIVATBANK',
'Swift2' => 'word2',
'Swift3' => 'word3',
'Swift4' => 'word4',
'Swift5' => 'word5',
'etc' => 'word6',
'etc..' => 'word7',
); 


echo http_build_query($swift) . "\n";
echo http_build_query($swift, '', '&amp;');

?>
```

My question is how to receive a string for example when I request the Swift3 with https://example.com/swifts.php?swift=Swift3
I want to receive in a page just the string **word3** but it shows me all the arrays like: PBANUA2XXXX=PRIVATBANK&Swift2=word2&Swift3=word3& etc etc....

How I can get what I request?

Comment: [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), with those two, `echo $swift[$_GET['swift']]`.

Comment: just comment the below two echo lines and add echo $swift[$_GET['swift']];die;

Comment: If you use @Script47's answer you want to add a check to check if `$_GET['swift']` is defined using [`isset()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Comment: @Script47, thank you for the answer, now just realized that I haven't ended your code with **;** at the end. Your answer was also working, just don't understand now about the isset()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get query string by using `$_GET`. 
Then use your array to get value

```
echo $swift[$_GET['swift']]; // as $_GET['swift'] = Swift3

so $swift[$_GET['swift']] = 'word3';
```

Comment: Note that this will throw a `Notice: Undefined index` error if the `swift` parameter is not defined. An additional check using [`isset()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is required to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @user1234 - I added the echo `$swift[$_GET['swift']];` below my code and removed that both http_build_query and seems like its working when I go to (http://example.com/swift.php?swift=anynumber)

@Tom Udding - I don't see the Notice: Undefined index error, what do you mean when the swift is not defined?

Comment: @haitashe For example, when the URL is something like `example.com/swift.php?swift=`, `$_GET['swift']` will be undefined. You never know what happens with the URL and thus your should implement a check to prevent any errors.

Comment: @TomUdding oh yeah, thanks, now I understood :)
If someone, also needs this, so I wrote this code after all my arrays:
`echo $swift[$_GET['swift']] ?? 'SWIFT doesn't exist';`